# Como transformar um texto selecionado para caixa baixa no VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Gostaria de transformar um trecho de código em caixa baixa no VSCode. Obter um efeito similar ao do <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> do Eclipse?

Algo que seja semelhante ao gif abaixo:

[image: transformando trecho de código em caixa baixa usando Eclipse]

Comment: A que eu conheço é selecionar o texto, `Ctrl+Shift+P` e digitar "lower" (ou upper), aparecendo a opção "Transform to Lowercase". Serve?

Comment: @Woss, o problema é texto não sequencial =/ Estou tentando ver aqui como cadastrar os atalhos, mas não estou conseguindo acessar o `settings` em modo plano, só através da GUI

Comment: Não sei se entendi o "texto não sequencial" xD

Comment: É um trecho de SQL em que os padrões da empresa dizem "nomes em minúsculo" e "palavras chaves do SQL em maiúsculo". Meu arquivo por hora está todo em caixa alta, então queria mudar o nome das colunas/tabelas para minúsculo, mas não tipos de colunas nem o `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer o meu _binding_, mas devo dizer que a GUI é horrível. Vou ver se consigo acessar algum modo mais textual de se fazer as coisas

Comment: Se te conforta, o Datagrip tem essa opção nas configurações (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyQFX.png) e basta utilizar `Ctrl-Alt-L` para formatar o arquivo completo xD

Comment: @Woss, conforta bastante! Mas teria de mudar toda a as pergunta para se adequar a isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara o VS Code tem uma forma de pesquisar e substituir strings usando `regex` aqui tem um artigo que pode te ajudar nisso https://dev.to/rfornal/vs-code-search-and-replace-regex-mn2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas como não manjo de Regex aqui tem um exemplo manual. Mas só consegui fazer com uma string por vez... Vale lembrar que vc pode tb definir se quer usar o `case sencitive` na substituição

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Criando um Atalho

Vc  pode  criar um atalho de teclado para transforma o que estiver selecionado para `Upper`, ou `Lower` `Case` conforme imagem abaixo. Basta vc entrar nos Settings e procurar por `Keyboard Shortcut`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não consegui fazer a letra específica mudar de caso. o `\U` no replace que eu esperaria que fizesse o trabalho não o fez =/

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado editei com a opção de vc criar um atalho, ai basta vc selecionar e usar o atalho, só que vc vai ter que fazer um Atalho para Upper e outro para Low

Answer (score 2):

1. Selecione o texto a ser transformado. Use Ctrl + L para selecionar
   toda a linha;
2. Abra Mostrar todos os comandos. Linux e Windows: Ctrl + Shift + P,
   Mac: ⇧⌘P;
3. Digite o comando, por exemplo: lowercase, uppercase, titlecase;
4. Aguarde o preenchimento automático;
5. Pressione Enter.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]